# How iconv and od handle endianness?

Tags: unicode

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16le | od -x
```

produces what seems to me like a big-endian result

```
0068    0065    006c    006c    006f    000a
```

whereas the same line without the 'le' produces, on a utf16le system (Osx)

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | od -x

fffe    6800    6500    6c00    6c00    6f00    0a00
```

Does od -x change the endianness?

Comment: You may use `od -t x1` (so printing a byte at a time) or you will get an additional conversion (which may confuse you)

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310) For the record, the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1570435/432690); an answer has been accepted there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`od` seems not changing anything, but `iconv` does. According to your output, this system maps `utf-16` to `utf-16be`.
Compare with output from my Ubuntu on x86-64:

```
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16le | hd
00000000  68 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00  6f 00 0a 00              |h.e.l.l.o...|
0000000c
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16le | od -x
0000000 0068 0065 006c 006c 006f 000a
0000014
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16be | hd
00000000  00 68 00 65 00 6c 00 6c  00 6f 00 0a              |.h.e.l.l.o..|
0000000c
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16be | od -x
0000000 6800 6500 6c00 6c00 6f00 0a00
0000014
```

One could call `od -t x1` instead of `hd` with similar output:

```
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16be | od -t x1
0000000 00 68 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 0a
0000014
```

it's like `hd` but without ASCII column.

But my Ubuntu maps utf-16 to utf-16le with BOM:

```
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | od -x
0000000 feff 0068 0065 006c 006c 006f 000a
0000016
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | hd
00000000  ff fe 68 00 65 00 6c 00  6c 00 6f 00 0a 00        |..h.e.l.l.o...|
0000000e
```

that is interesting why your OS X system is configured opposite way. I see no real reason for this; maybe it is some weird legacy or compile configuration error. Does it have documentation with mentioning of this moment?

Comment: If you specify utf-16, you are saying "I don't care about the endianness, I just want UTF-16 with a BOM." The macOS version uses GNU `libiconv` which always outputs big-endian data no matter what. Your Ubuntu version is almost certainly the one provided by `glibc` instead, which uses native endianness. Not an error, just two different implementations making different choices in a situation where that is permitted

Comment: Thank you. `echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | od -x` gives little-endian (on OS X Catalina) fffe    6800    6500    6c00    6c00    6f00    0a00. The '-x' and '-t x2' give little-endian and -t x1 gives big endian, because it splits words.